# How many DTOs should I create?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, dto

I got some services where I return DTOs,
now I can reuse the same DTO for different methods.

let's say I have the following interface:

```
List<ProductDTO> GetProductsByReseller(int reseller)
List<ProductDTO> GetProductsByManufacturer(int Manufacturer)
List<ProductDTO> GetProductsByCategory(int Category)
```

using the same DTO for them is absolutely valid I think, as they all have really the same fields.

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Reseller { get; set; }
    public int Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have some other methods, for example:

```
List<ProductDTO> GetProductsWithAdminInfoByCategory(int Category)
```

For this method I have to extend the DTO with some additional fields.

```
     #region only for admin
     public int KnownDefects { get; set; }
     public DateTime InStockSince { get; set; }   
     #endregion //only for admin
```

Is it ok to reuse the existing DTO and simply extend it?
Or should I create a new DTO because some fields would never be used from that Method?

What I think: If only 1 or 2 fields are new (never used in the other cases), maybe it's ok, as I not have to create a duplicate DTO and the tradeof for maintaining 2 DTOs instead of 1 is ok. Probably it would be good if I derive a AdminProductDTO from ProductDTO, but I don't know if inheritation is valid for DTOs.

Well am I wrong?
What would be a good treshold value (nbr of changes), from when on to create a new DTO?

**Update:**
If I expose a service in WCF that would expose the ProductDTO, will it have to transmit the *KnownDefects* and *InStockSince* properties if they are not set or null?
Or is WCF clever enough and not need to transmit undefined/null properties at all? (In that case I wouldn't mind to have only one DTO with 2 properties that are not always used.)

**Another Update:**
Well if I inherit ProductAdminDTO from ProductDTO, can I still call the following service with it(that would only accept a ProductDTO)?

```
bool SaveProduct(ProductDTO)
```

Well I guess I could simply try that out myself, will update later :)

Comment: there is lot of solutions. inheritance, composition, Tuple<T,K> whatever you think is best for u. do it

Comment: So if inheritation is no problem, I will simply inherit the DTO and then I don't have to worry if I call the DoSomethingWithTheDTO method. Will quickly update my question.

Comment: I just got that info from a good guy: "in wcf point of view, your data contract is the message structure definition, not the in-memory object, I think It may be not possible." That's what I am worrying about!

Comment: well I noticed that I use the "extended" DTO only when I not go over WCF, therefor I didn't mark it with the [DataMember] Attribute. So I should not really care. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems you are stuck at classic inheritance Vs Composition problem.

Think whether ProductionWithAdminInfo "ISA" Product? 
I don't think it satisfies ISA relationship. An extra admin information is just another property of the product.

So composition seems good choice here. ProductWithAdminInfoDTO contains ProductDTO and AdminInfoDTo.

Comment: So you think it is valid to inherit DTOs, right? Well I will quickly update my question to make one of my toughts more obvious. I see your answer not goes in the direction I wanted. :)

Comment: if there is a direction you want, just do it. use your intuition:)

Comment: Mark yours as answer even if I am still not sure, I could pass a InheritedDTO to a a service with a service contract for a ParentDTO.